# How can I solve ImportError "scipy_csr" for XGBoost?

Tags: python, xgboost

Need help with the following problem I'm facing when trying to install XGBoost. After installing all requirements (brew/gcc/cmake etc), I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name '**scipy_csr**' from 'xgboost.compat'
> (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/compat.py)

Just wanted to know if anyone here have come across this issue & if there is anyway I can troubleshoot/solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can search `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/compat.py` for `scipy` and see if you can find some function / class / variablle / whatever that has a similar name. If not, you could create a variable with that name inside that file and see what happens. Please note though that this may cause other errors (most probably a `TypeError`).

Comment: This helped indirectly! When going through the codes, found out the problem was that it was throwing an exception because I haven't install ed one library package when "compat.py" was executed.

Answer (score 1):

As guided by "Programmer" above, I looked into "compat.py" file and found the following exception handling:

```
try:
 import sparse
 import scipy.sparse as scipy_sparse
 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as scipy_csr
 SCIPY_INSTALLED = True
except ImportError:
 sparse = False
 scipy_sparse = False
 scipy_csr: Any = object
 SCIPY_INSTALLED = False
```

All I needed to do was to "pip install sparse" package and it solved the problem. I can run XGBoost smoothly now.